# Use Database in C#

Tags: c#, database

I recently write a simple program that use database.

I've created an DB1.MDF and get data from it.

When I try to do Select from its Table (i.e. Table1), it gets run time error!

How I should do that?!

One more question:

I've created Data Grid View and put data in that. Now, how I can for example use column[2] of it (e.g. column[2] in my dataGridView is LastName and I want to save all LastNames in one String).

Here is my Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

     conn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
           AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB1.mdf;
           Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

     conn.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

     cmd.Connection = conn;

     cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, LastName from Table1 WHERE Name == Joe ";

     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

     da.SelectCommand = cmd;

     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);

     dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
     conn.Close();
 }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Columns[0].ToString();
 }
```

Comment: What runtime error are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select query should be like this

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, LastName from Table1 WHERE Name = 'Joe'";
```

And for your second question, you could use something like this

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     dataGirdView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList()
         .ForEach(r => builder.Append(r.Cells[2].Value));
     textBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Oded Thanks. From all the formatting I've done on stackoverflow, I been using ` instead of `'` all over the place.

Comment: @ Bala R: thanks for your help...I found my mistake in SELECT command! If I want to use another SELECT right after this SELECT and put that into DataGridView2, I have write all these code agian?

Comment: @ Bala R: Can you explain a little about button2_Click codes? Is it only way to get data from specific column of DataGridView?

Comment: @ha.M.ed I'm not sure about the question on another select (can you rephrase it?) but the button2_click basically loops through the rows and appends the value in cell[2] for each row to a stringbuilder instance. You can use a for loop if you would like that instead.

Comment: @ Bala R - I mean when I showed data in DataGridView1, I write cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID from Table1 WHERE Name = 'Mick' " and put reuslt in DataGridView2 (use same SqlDataAdapter and DataTable objects), DataGridView1 and DataGridView2 show me all rows without any Selection!

Comment: @ Bala R - If I don't want to use StringBuilder, Is there another way to put data in textBox1.Text ? any easier and understandale way?!

Comment: @ha.M.ed you can use regular string concatenation instead.
`dataGirdView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().ToList()
         .ForEach(r => textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + r.Cells[2].Value);`

Answer (score 0):

This query seems wrong.

```
SELECT ID, Name, LastName from Table1 WHERE Name == Joe
```

Can you try this?

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, LastName from Table1 WHERE Name = 'Joe'"
```

Also, please post the details of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Bala R has it right, the == operator does not exist in SQL, therefore if your testing for an equality you should use the single = operator. And if you're comparing strings (varchar or nvarchar in SQL) you should put them in single quotes i.e. 'Joe'.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Louis! By your own admission, your answer doesn't add anything to the discussion. Perhaps this would be better as a comment on @Bala's answer?